# Angular - Check/Uncheck All Checkboxes

Tags: angular, forms, checkbox

my job is to do the following functionality. I have 3 checkboxes and after selecting one I want the other two to also be selected.

I use a ready-made component to create the checkbox.

```
<form [formGroup]="data" name="name" >
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form__element">
      <nb-checkbox name="groupname" value="Check All" label="Check All" formControlName="isAgree" [(ngModel)]="myVar2" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></nb-checkbox>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="features__box">
    <section class="agreements">
          <ul class="features__list">
        <li class="features__item" *ngFor="let agreement of data.agreements.value">
          <div class="form__element">
            <nb-checkbox name="groupname" value={{agreement.description}} label={{agreement.description}} [checked]="myVar2" (change)="myVar2 = !myVar2"></nb-checkbox>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    <section class="statements">
          <ul class="features__list">
        <li class="features__item" *ngFor="let statement of data.statements.value">
          <div class="form__element">
            <nb-checkbox name="groupname" value={{statement.description}} label={{statement.description}} [checked]="myVar2" (change)="myVar2 = !myVar2"></nb-checkbox>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>
</form>
```

I added `[(ngModel)] =" myVar2 "[ngModelOptions] =" {standalone: true} "` to my main checkbox, and I added `[checked] =" myVar2 "(change) =" myVar2 =! myVar2 to my next checkbox.`
In the `file.component.ts` file I added`myVar2: boolean = false;`

However, the above solution does not work. I get the following errors in the console

```
    
    ERROR in src/app/file.component.html:64:66 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngModelOptions' since
it isn't a known property of 'nb-checkbox'.
    1. If 'nb-checkbox' is an Angular component and it has 'ngModelOptions' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'nb-checkbox' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
    3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
    
    64                   formControlName="isAgree" [(ngModel)]="myVar2" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></nb-checkbox>
                                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    
      src/app/file.component.ts:14:16
        14   templateUrl: './file.component.html',
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Error occurs in the template of component CeidgPositiveComponent.
    src/app/file.component.html:94:121 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'checked' since it isn't a known property of 'nb-checkbox'.
    1. If 'nb-checkbox' is an Angular component and it has 'checked' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'nb-checkbox' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
    3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
    
    94                     <nb-checkbox name="groupname" value={{statement.description}} label={{statement.description}} [checked]="myVar2" (change)="myVar2 = !myVar2"></nb-checkbox>
                                                                                                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    
      src/app/file.component.ts:14:16
        14   templateUrl: './file.component.html',
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Error occurs in the template of component File.
```

I have imported modules `import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@ angular / forms'; import {NgxsModule} from '@ ngxs / store';`

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: You need to import the `NbCheckboxModule`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating my answer as per our discussion in comments, to check/uncheck all checkboxes.

**component.ts**

```
checklist

checkUncheckAll(evt) {
  this.checklist.forEach((c) => c.isSelected = evt.target.checked)
}

ngOnInit() {
this.checklist = [
    {id:1,value:'Elenor Anderson',isSelected:false},
    {id:2,value:'Caden Kunze',isSelected:false},
    {id:3,value:'Ms. Hortense Zulauf',isSelected:false},
    {id:4,value:'Grady Reichert',isSelected:false},
    {id:5,value:'Dejon Olson',isSelected:false},
    {id:6,value:'Jamir Pfannerstill',isSelected:false},
    {id:7,value:'Aracely Renner DVM',isSelected:false},
    {id:8,value:'Genoveva Luettgen',isSelected:false}
  ];
}
```

In your template

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="text-center mt-5">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">
              <input type="checkbox" name="list_name" value="m1" (change)="checkUncheckAll($event)"/> <strong>Select/ Unselect All</strong>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let item of checklist">
              <input type="checkbox" [checked]="item.isSelected" name="list_name" value="{{item.id}}"/>
              {{item.value}}
            </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Working [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-z1qcvq)

Comment: But nb-checkbox is my custom component, I don't use the ui library you suggested

Comment: I see, you said your are using ready-made component and named with `nb-` prefix so I thought using library, so you are using your own custom code correct?

Comment: true, this is what my checkbox looks like

```  
    <input #cb type="checkbox" [attr.id]="inputId" [attr.name]="name" [readonly]="readonly" [value]="value"
      [checked]="checked" (focus)="onFocus()" (blur)="onBlur()" [ngClass]="{'ui-state-focus':focused}"
      (change)="handleChange($event)">

```

Comment: @Doe what is your exact requirements, you need a form where multiple checkboxes listed and one parent checkbox with Check All label and all you need to click that parent Check All checkbox and all other checkboxes should get checked?

Comment: I would like to have several checkboxes on the page and click one and it all checked.

Comment: I found such an example on the Internet https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-abelrm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html, but it does not work for me

Comment: @Doe From those several checkboxes you need to check any one checkbox it should check all and vice versa (if uncheck any one should uncheck all?)

Comment: If you check the box with the label - select all - all should be checked. If there are any fields that are not called - check all-, I only check that field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220345/discussion-between-kamran-khatti-and-doe).